# list all properties with [XmlAttribute] of given class

Tags: c#, .net-4.0

For example I have a simple class

```
class SomeCfg
{
    [XmlAttribute("ArchivePath")]
    public string ArchivePath { get; set; }
}
```

As it can be seen given class have one property with Xml**Attribute**. But when program execution comes to that code

```
 var t = typeof (SomeCfg);
 var props = t.GetProperties().Where(
    prop => Attribute.IsDefined(prop, typeof(XmlAttribute)));
```

Runtime throws exception

```
System.ArgumentException: Type passed in must be derived from System.Attribute or System.Attribute itself.
```

Of course when I saw type hierarchy I realized it's true (I will not go into why this does not inherits from that class).

My question is how to list these properties (creating a class that inherits from XmlAttribute and System.Attribute is not an option in that case).

According to question tag .Net version is 4.0.

Comment: Sorry, of course this line was missing. I corrected the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is it possible that you used [`System.Xml.XmlAttribute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of [`System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlattributeattribute(v=vs.110).aspx)?

`System.Xml.XmlAttribute` is used to represent an attribute from the xml document.
`System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute` specifies that the XmlSerializer must serialize the class member as an XML attribute.

Comment: Yes, the line with attribute query should look like this
var props = t.GetProperties().Where(
    prop => Attribute.IsDefined(prop, typeof(XmlAttributeAttribute)))

Answer (score 1):

You can get Properties containing **XMLAttribute** from following code..

```
var props = t.GetProperties()
             .Where(prop =>
                 prop.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(XmlAttributeAttribute), false).Any(PropType => PropType.GetType() == typeof(XmlElementAttribute) ||
                                                         PropType.GetType() == typeof(XmlAttributeAttribute)));
```

if you don't want to use full **LINQ** then this post is also helpful for you.

[Serialize all properties in a class as attributes instead of elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24005763/serialize-all-properties-in-a-class-as-attributes-instead-of-elements)